# Moving cells from one table to another in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to create an application with multiple table views that uses and implements Core Data. I would like the user to be able to select cells in one table and move them to another (like in Apple's mail application) using either a check accessory or a selectedCell method with an action sheet. I'm stuck because I don't know if you are actually moving the cell to another table or if you are adding a copy to the new table and deleting the original. Basically, I'm asking for a basic example of cell movement to give me a push in the right direction.

Comment: Can you show us what you have already tried?

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet. What I've got so far is the initial tables with the ability to add cells (obviously), Core Data functionality, and the ability for cells to push to a detail view displaying info unique to each cell. Just asking for examples/ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be moving cells.  The model for a table view is an array.  Move things between the arrays and tell the tables that their model has changed.

```
id somePartOfMyModel = [self.arrayA objectAtIndex:someIndexPath.row];
[self.arrayA removeObject:somePartOfMyModel];
[self.arrayB addObject:somePartOfMyModel];

// the simplest, non-animated way to update the tables.
// I'd advise getting this working first, then later trying fancier UI to indicate changes
[self.tableViewA reloadData];
[self.tableViewB reloadData];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it doesn't have to look cool at all. I'm building an inventory system for the company I work at in an attempt to "snag" a better job. I also can't include the exact sample code either so as to not violate the terms of my employment with any "company sensitive" information.

Comment: So the next scenario is that each cell pushes a detail view displaying information that is unique to each "item" the cell represents. When I add the object to the second array, does it keep all of the information from its detail view as well or does that need to be removed/added as well?

Comment: What the next view needs ought to be carried by the model.  The canonical example is of blog posts.  Lets say arrayA an arrayB are arrays of posts.  The 'partOfMyModel' is a post.  It should have properties like title and comments and so forth.  When the user selects from the tables (backed by those arrays), the app's behavior is to pass that part of the model to the next view controller, a detail view controller that interrogates that model and presents it properties.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that the attributes should display in the detail view in the same way as the original table? At this point each entity has only 2 attributes that are displayed in 2 labels in the cell, and the detail view displays the same information, but the detail view is where any editing of these fields takes place and updates the labels in the cell accordingly.

Comment: That sounds about right. The detail view controller can present text views or text fields, pre filled with nesting values in the model. User will edit text and indicate they are done.  Detail view will update the model and pop back to the prior view with the tables. The tables should reload on viewWillAppear. That way they will be up to date.

Comment: You are beyond helpful. Thank you so much. I've been stuck on this for like a month because I assumed it had to do with the reordering of the cells across two tables. Sounds crazy I know, but I was running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You would not be technically moving the cell to the other table. The way I would go about doing this would be to pass the `NSManagedObjectContextID` of the item between the tables, depending on how large your entities are and if the tables are in the same view controller.

Comment: Ok so you're just passing the NSString. The tables are in separate view controllers and the entities aren't large, only 2 attributes; may add a third. So after the string has been passed I can just use the cell identifier in the destination Table View?

Comment: You would pass along the CoreData object to the next view controller, add it to the array that the table pulls its data from, reload the table.

Comment: If you only pass along the NSManagedObjectContextID you would pass that to the next view controller, fetch the object from core data based on its' NSManagedObjectContextID, add the returned item to your table array and reload the table.